# Inference Lemma Proof?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a subset of $\mathcal{L_0}$, $\phi$ and $\psi$ formulas. If $\Gamma \vdash \psi$ and $\Gamma \vdash (\psi\to \phi)$ then $\Gamma \vdash \phi$.

**Proof:** Let $\langle \phi_1,\dots,\phi_n\rangle$ be a $\Gamma$-proof of $\psi$, thus $\phi_n = \psi$. Let $\langle \psi_1,\dots,\psi_m\rangle$ be a $\Gamma$-proof of $(\psi\to\phi)$.

Here's where I get lost.

Then $\langle\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n, \psi_1,\dots,\psi_m,\phi\rangle$ is a $\Gamma$-proof and thus $\Gamma \vdash \phi$.

Where is $\phi$ coming from tacked on at the end? Why is this a gamma proof? I feel that for the $\Gamma$-proof of $(\psi\to\phi)$, $\psi_m = (\psi\to\phi)$. So the concatenation of the two should be $\langle\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n, \psi_1,\dots,\psi_m\rangle$ which leads nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you have a rule of inference that allows you to infer $\varphi$ from the pair of formulas $\psi\to\varphi$ and $\psi$. If so, the final step of the proof is justified by the earlier appearance of $\varphi_n$ and $\psi_m$ in the proof.

Comment: I think that the concatenation is a gamma proof by a theorem, and a sequence is a gamma proof if for each $i\leq n$, at least one of (a) $\psi_i\in \Gamma$ (b) $\psi_i$ is a logical axiom or (c) there are $j_1$ and $j_2$ both less than $i$ such that $\phi_{j_2} = (\phi_{j_1} \to \phi_i)$ This (c) condition allows us to tack on $\phi$

Comment: @Kevin: And that’s what you have: the condition holds for $\langle\varphi_1,\ldots\varphi_n\rangle$ and $\langle\psi_1,\ldots,\psi_m\rangle$ by hypothesis, so it holds for their concatenation, and you can append $\varphi$ to that concatenation because of the earlier presence of $\psi\to\varphi$ and $\psi$ in the proof.

Comment: Is $\phi \in \Gamma$? satisfying (a) as well?

Comment: @Kevin: $\varphi$ needn’t be in $\Gamma$.